# Similar function to numpy.dot with nalgebra in Rust

Tags: matrix, rust, matrix-multiplication, nalgebra

I recently started to use [`nalgebra`](https://nalgebra.org/), but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do a [regular dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), like below:

[image: dot product of two matricies]

This is similar to how in Python, you can do this:

```py
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
arr2 = np.array([[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]])

print(arr1.dot(arr2)) # [[ 58  64][139 154]]
```

But when I do this in Rust with `nalgebra`, I get the wrong result:

```rust
let matrix1 = Matrix3x2::from_vec(vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
let matrix2 = Matrix2x3::from_vec(vec![7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]);

println!("{:?}", matrix1); // [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] 
println!("{:?}", matrix2); // [[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]
println!("{:?}", matrix1 * matrix2); // [[39, 54, 69], [49, 68, 87], [59, 82, 105]]
```

I also tried other functions like `mul`, `cross`, and `dot`, and all of them either didn't even work on these matrices or gave the wrong answer.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've switched the matrix dimensions: your `matrix1` is a `Matrix3x2`, which means it has *3 rows and 2 columns*  and similarly `matrix2` has 2 rows and 3 columns.

Try it with:

```
let matrix1 = Matrix2x3::new(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
let matrix2 = Matrix3x2::new(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
```

Note that `from_vec` constructs a matrix in *column-major* order. If your data comes from a vector in row-major order, you will need to use [`from_row_slice`](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/latest/nalgebra/base/struct.Matrix.html#method.from_row_slice).

Comment: So, `nalgebra` always uses a list of *columns*, not a list of rows? Is there a way I can just work with row-first as the default (it's easier for me to think about).